# Can't get desired column distribution in CSS Grid

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I'm trying to create a grid with dynamic number of rows and columns.
But all columns should be vertically aligned.

```css
.sequenz-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(100px, 1fr));
  gap: 2px;
}

.sequenz-row {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: minmax(140px, 1fr) repeat(auto-fill, minmax(100px, 1fr));
  gap: 2px;
}

.sequenz-column {
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #e0e0e0;
}

.title-column {
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #e0e0e0;
}
```

```html
<div class="steps-chart-container">
  <div class="sequenz-container">
    <div class="sequenz-row" *ngFor="let row of [1, 2, 3]">
      <div class="title-column"></div>
      <div class="sequenz-column" *ngFor="let priceStep of priceSteps">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

The problem is, that I cant figure out how to force everything to stay correct
when resizing.
Already small resizes are messing up the grid and pushing columns into the next line.
See here:
[image]

What can I do to get the desired outcome.

I want all columns to be on top of each other an to stay in the same line when resizing the window.

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex). - **Your current code does not demonstrate the issue.**

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.